# SQL - Return all people who had events happening in a 24 month period

Tags: sql, hive

I've been struggling with this for a while now, and honestly have no clue how to do it.
I have a huge base of events made by my customers, it kinda looks like this:[image]

And I also have a list of event_id [37474, 37475, 250200021, 25020023]

So what i need is a sql code that will return all of my customers (PERSON_ID) that fulfil the following condition:
**At least 3 events that are in the list, happening within a 24 month timeframe**
So in the example above it should return person_id: 100046, 154826

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: please provide data and expected results as text in your question, [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At least 3 events that are in the list, happening within a 24 month timeframe

You can look two rows ahead using `lead()` and then use date comparisons to see if the second row is less than two years in the future.  Date functions depend very much on the database, but the idea is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(date, 2) over (partition by person_id order by date) as next_date_2
      from t
     ) t
where next_date_2 < date + interval '2' year;
```

This returns each row in the original table that meets the conditions.  If you just want the persons:

```
select distinct person_id
from (select t.*,
             lead(date, 2) over (partition by person_id order by date) as next_date_2
      from t
     ) t
where next_date_2 < date + interval '2' year;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if a person has at least three event and all the events happened in 24 months time frame you can use group by with having clause:

```
select persion_id from mytable 
group by person_id
having count(*)>=3 and max(date)<=dateadd(month, 24, min(date))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select person_id from (select person_id, count(event_id) event_count from table123 where (timestamp > now()-interval 24 month) group by person_id) t where event_count >= 3;
```

Replace "table123" with your table name.

Answer (score 0):

Following Gordon's answer, I was able to adapt my code to Hive. I had to use date_sub() instead of INTERVAL, but it worked just as well!

```
SELECT t.* FROM    
(SELECT *,
lead(dataatendimento, 2) over (partition by beneficiario order by date) as next_date_2
FROM my_table
and event_id in (37474, 37475, 37229, 37228, 37218, 37220, 37222, 37223, 37225, 37476, 37478, 37221, 37224, 37227, 37477, 37219)
) t
where date_sub(next_date_2, 720) < date
```

Thank you Gordon!